# How to put ellipsis at the axis of chartfx graph?

Tags: c#, winforms, chartfx

I'm working on ChartFX for windows forms, have a problem. My application must works on screens that have an small size (i.e. 1440x900), I need to display several charts on the same screen (I cannot change it). So, when it happens the axis labels of my charts (charts of the ChartFX) looks cutted.

Somebody does know how a can add ellipsis instead cut labels for the axis labels using chartFX ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't found any way to do that, seem that it is not possible with the standard components for ChartFx.